# post/passing data array in react native using axios not caught by ENDPOINT

Tags: php, react-native, axios, crud

i'm trying to make simple CRUD using axios in react-native, when i'm trying to create an add data function i'm having problems passing array data to endpoint,

note: the endpoint I created using php native,

I've tried my endpoint using POSTMAN 3 times, and it worked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZMuu.png)

however, when I try to POST using axios in react native, the data in the array is not caught by the endpoint.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'

export class CreatelData extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             title:'',
             description: '',
        }
    }

    onSubmit = () => {
        
        const dataInput = {
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
        }
        console.warn(dataInput)
        
        axios.post('http://my_local_ip/fullstack/smooth_test/backend/api.php?on=create', dataInput)
        .then( response => {
            // resultSend(response.data)
            console.log('res: ', response.data)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('err: ', err) )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={tampilan.container}>
                <Text style={tampilan.header}>POST</Text>
                
                <View>
                    <View style={tampilan.row}>
                        <Text>Title :</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            style={tampilan.textInput}
                            placeholder="Enter Title..."
                            onChangeText= { (value) => {this.setState( {title: value} )} }
                        ></TextInput>
                    </View>
                    <View style={tampilan.row}>
                        <Text>Description :</Text>
                        <TextInput
                        style={tampilan.textInputArea}
                            placeholder="Enter Description..."
                            onChangeText= { (value) => {this.setState( {description: value} )} }

                        ></TextInput>
                    </View>
                        
                    <View style={tampilan.row}>
                        <TouchableOpacity 
                            style={tampilan.btnSubmit}
                            onPress={ () => this.onSubmit() }
                        >
                            <Text style={tampilan.textbtn}>Submit</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

however, when I try to view the array using console.warm(data), the data has contents, and is not empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW4M2.png)

anyone please advice and solutions..

Comment: try to pass data like this to axios
{data: dataInput}

Comment: just the same, it not work :(

Comment: in your php code how are you getting the data. Can you paste your code

Answer (score 0):

I found some help here  [react native axios](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-axios-react-fr)

axios post look like this :

```
const user = {
  name: this.state.name
};

axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, { user })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
  })
```

then your code code could be look like this

```
const dataInput = {
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
        }
        console.warn(dataInput)
    
    axios.post('http://my_local_ip/fullstack/smooth_test/backend/api.php?on=create', {dataInput})
    .then( response => {
        // resultSend(response.data)
        console.log('res: ', response.data)
    })
```